# Can't append label to highchart pie chart

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I'm trying to add a custom label to a highcharts pie chart.  The label is going to (eventually) be center, bottom aligned and display some html data.  The problem is the label does not show on the chart, trying to use 'renderer'.  I'm quite new to highcharts, what am I doing wrong?

```
$('#div_graph_0_1').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    type: 'pie'
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'NEW VISITORS'
                },
                subtitle:{
                    text: pieSubtitleTotal,
                    style: { color: '#f07600' }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{point.y}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                            halo: {
                            size: 9,
                            attributes: {
                                fill: '#f07600'}
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            connectorWidth: 0,
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.y}',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'New',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Repeat',
                        y: subtitleTotal,
                        color: '#fff',
                        borderColor: '#f07600',
                        borderWidth: 2
                    }, {
                        name: 'New',
                        color: '#f07600',
                        borderColor: '#f07600',
                        y: pieTotalVisitors,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                        }]
                    }],
                     navigation: {
                    buttonOptions: {
                        enabled: false
                        }
                     },
                     function(chart) { // on complete

                         chart.renderer.text('This text is <span style="color: red">styled</span> and <a href="http://example.com">linked</a>', 0, 0)
                             .css({
                                 color: '#4572A7',
                                 fontSize: '16px'
                             })
                             .add();
                     }
            });
```

Comment: You have the syntax error, fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/68bcoLqf/

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, as your rendered text IS there and present on the chart. What you needed to define was the expected X and Y values where you wanted the text to be placed.

I discovered this because of the "y" in "styled":

[image]

If you define a different y value in your `renderer.text` call, say, `100`, you get this:

[image]

Here is the syntax you should follow:

```
chart.renderer.text('Your text', X_VALUE, Y_VALUE)
```

In my above example, I set your text to:

```
chart.renderer.text('Your text', 0, 100)
```

... which puts it 100 pixels down from the top of the chart.

You're going to have to define these values manually; there's no out-of-the-box way to say "bottom-aligned, center-aligned." To make this more versatile, what you could do is capture the height and width of your container div and calculate the x and y values that way.

You can do this by fixing the height and width of your chart in a stylesheet declaration, defining JavaScript variables outside your chart options, and then calling those variables from the `renderer.text` declaration:

```
// in your inline stylesheet
#container: { width: '650px', height: '450px' }

// variables defined before your chart options
var chartHeight = $('#container').height();
var chartWidth = $('#container').width();

// in your renderer code
 chart.renderer.text('Your text', chartWidth * 0.5, chartHeight - 100)
```

In the above example, your rendered text would start at 50% of your chart's width and 100 pixels from the bottom of your chart.

One point to keep in mind: you mentioned an HTML table. In that case, I'd suggest switching `renderer.text` to `renderer.html`. That will allow many more HTML elements to be rendered in the final chart.

I hope all of this has been helpful!